SP2019 API - Reference for complete List and Library Item Properties
I am looking for a complete reference source (URL) for all the SP2019 List and Library & File  properties that can be used with API endpoint operators (select, filter, etc.).

Here is a sort of "entry point" to the MS documentation on the SharePoint REST API:
Get to know the SharePoint REST service
From there you should be able to find more detailed and technical references.
Personally, though, I have found that the JSOM (SP.js) documentation provides slightly better insight into the default/built-in properties and methods of the SharePoint objects, and the correct syntax for their REST counterparts, than the "official" REST API documentation.
Here's the entry point for the SP.js documentation:
SP namespace (sp.js)
To see what I'm talking about, though, let's take a look at an example.  If you look at the documentation for the SP.List object, you will see a list of all the methods and properties, and then at the bottom of the page are the URI structures to access SP.List objects via the REST API.
Then, if you look at, say, the first property listed, the SP.List.allowContentTypes property, if you look at that page you will see the URI structure to access that particular property.
The same is true for almost all the other objects and their methods and properties - each page will have the JSOM documentation first, but will have the REST URI structure at the end.
All that being said... to be pedantic, you will never find "complete" documentation for all of the properties you can use with operators like $select and $filter because you can use those operators on custom columns that you have added to a list or library. Obviously MS can't provide any documentation concerning those.

Dylan! Thank you very much!  I sensed that there wasn't a complete reference. Many thank!! Cheers-
